# OpenGL ES texture wrap giving weird results sometimes

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am using following method to create OpenGL ES texture on android.

```
 private int createTexture(int width, int height, int i) {
    int[] mTextureHandles = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, mTextureHandles, 0);
    int textureID = mTextureHandles[0];
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0 + i);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    return textureID;
}
```

Then uploading a `bitmap` to this `texture` and simply rendering it using `GLSurfaceView's Renderer`.

> Most of the times it is working as expected,

[image: normal working image]

> But randomly the `texture` is displayed like this. (here `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` mode is `GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`

[image: clamp mode used]

After changing wrap mode.

> If `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` = `GLES20.GL_REPEAT` then (again randomly) texture is displayed like this(notice the color change).

[image: repeat mode used]

**I have already tried using power of 2 texture.**

Code for `vertex buffer`

```
 private FloatBuffer createVertexBuffer(RectF glCoords) {

  //   RectF glCoords contains gl vertices.
  //   current Rect read from Logcat.
  //   left = -0.5833333, top = 0.5, right = 0.5833334, bottom = -0.5

    float[] vertices = new float[]{glCoords.left, glCoords.top, 0, 1, // V1 - top left
            glCoords.left, glCoords.bottom, 0, 1, // V2 - bottom left
            glCoords.right, glCoords.bottom, 0, 1, // V3 - bottom right
            glCoords.right, glCoords.top, 0, 1 // V4 - top right
    };
    FloatBuffer vBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * bytesPerFloat)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    vBuffer.put(vertices);
    vBuffer.position(0);
    return vBuffer;
}
```

IndicesBuffer is not used as I am using `Triangle-Fan` to render triangles.

```
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 6);
```

It would be really helpful if someone can point out as to what could be causing this

Comment: The brown-ish part is unlikely to be caused by wrapping modes. There has to be some geometry drawn. If it's random, look for uninitalized variables in the code that fills the vertex/index buffers.

Comment: @Vlad thanks for ur comment, I have added vertex buffer code also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your geometry seems to be a 4-vertex rectangle (quad), but the code wants to draw a fan with 6 vertices - `GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 6);`

Those extra 2 vertices aren't initialized, not specified in the vertex array. OpenGL will read beyond the defined part of the array. The results would be random, and I'd even expect crashes.

Replace 6 with 4 in `glDrawArrays()` call, this should fix the problem.

Comment:  thanks man!! It was obvious but still somehow I missed it.